# Prolog - Why is member/2 not working here?

Tags: prolog, member

I don't know why this isn't working... here's the code.

```
cameToTheParty(date(15,9,2011), flor).
cameToTheParty(date(22,9,2011), marina).
cameToTheParty(date(15,9,2011), pablo).
cameToTheParty(date(22,9,2011), pablo).
cameToTheParty(date(15,9,2011), leo).
cameToTheParty(date(22,9,2011), flor).
cameToTheParty(date(15,9,2011), fer).
cameToTheParty(date(22,9,2011), mati).

cameToThePartyThatDay(Peoples, Date):-
    bagof(X,cameToTheParty(Date,X),Peoples).
```

When I try

```
?- cameToThePartyThatDay(People,Day).
```

it says

> ```
>  People = [flor, pablo, leo, fer],
>  Day = date(15, 9, 2011) ; 
>  People = [marina, pablo, flor, mati], 
>  Day = date(22, 9, 2011).
> ```

But, when I try the following with a variable date's field, or an actual date, like...

```
member(X,cameToThePartyThatDay(People,date(15,9,2011))).
```

it just says

> false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that member is trying to find an element from the list `cameToThePartyThatDay(People,date(15,9,2011))`, which is not, in fact, a list.

What you want to do is:

```
cameToThePartyThatDay(People,date(15,9,2011)),
member(X,People).
```

... so that People is unified with the list of people who came to the party that day, and then member can pull elements from the list of People.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, so how is that
cameToThePartyThatDay(People,date(15,9,2011)).
returns something that looks like a list in SWI-prolog?
`> ?- cameToThePartyThatDay(People,date(15,9,2011)).
 > People = [flor, pablo, leo, fer].`

Comment: @newbie You're confusing a return with a unification - what 
`> ?- cameToThePartyThatDay(People,date(15,9,2011)). > People = [flor, pablo, leo, fer].` says is that `cameToThePartyThatDay(People,date(15,9,2011)).` is true when `People = [flor, pablo, leo, fer].` - from thereon out, People will be unified with the list `[flor, pablo, leo, fer]`. Prolog predicates never return, they only succeed or fail.

Answer (score 3):

```
member(X,cameToThePartyThatDay(People,date(15,9,2011)))
```

is a wrong way to use `member/2` because

```
cameToThePartyThatDay(People,date(15,9,2011))
```

isn't a list.

A right way could be

```
cameToThePartyThatDay(People, date(15, 9, 2011)),
member(X, People)
```

Answer (score 3):

For Prolog, the boldface part in the following expression:

```
member(X,cameToThePartyThatDay(People,date(15,9,2011))).
```

Is **not** a call. In fact predicates are **not functions**: they do **not return** anything. According to Prolog the boldface part is a **functor**.

In order to let it work, you first call `cameToThePartyThatDay` and then you use `People` in the `member/2` predicate, like:

```
cameToThePartyThatDay(People,date(15,9,2011)),
member(X,People).
```